# How do you apply a multivariable function to a 100x100 array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use python to compute the output of a function, say:

$f(x) = x + y$

Where x and y are the coordinates of the point in the array. So, the point 5, 5 would have the value 10. This will essentially generate an image of (x,y) and an associated pixel intensity value.

Right now I have a 100x100 dataframe in Python/Pandas, and want to know how to actually perform this calculation. My best guess is iterate over each row, and using the index of the row (y) and the index of the element (x), pass these two values into the function and set the point to that value.

This is essentially a basic multivariable graphing problem. Was hoping someone had some experience doing stuff like this. Thank you!

Comment: Generally, yes, you need to loop and pass. But depending on your function (like in this case of sum), usually you can create a mesh grid and pass it to `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numpy functions `fromfunction` and `indices`.  They'll probably do what you want.

```
import numpy as np

np.fromfunction( lambda r, c: r+c, shape = (5,5)) 
# array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
#        [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
#        [2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
#        [3., 4., 5., 6., 7.],
#        [4., 5., 6., 7., 8.]])
```

`fromfunction` takes a function as the first argument then the shape.  It uses the axes' indices in the function.  The function requires as many arguments as there are dims in the shape.

```
np.indices((3,3))
# array([[[0, 0, 0],     # Row coordinates
#         [1, 1, 1],
#         [2, 2, 2]],
#
#        [[0, 1, 2],     # Column coordinates
#         [0, 1, 2],
#         [0, 1, 2]]])
```

These can be used as function arguments to drive your results.

There are also np.ogrid and np.mgrid which generate np.arrays to use in any calculations.  A lot depends on exactly what you want to do.

**Edit:** np.fromfunction with keyword arguments.

```
def test ( a, b, c, m0=1, m1 =1):  # Specify function with kwargs.
    return a * m0 + b * m1 + c

np.fromfunction(test, (4, 3, 5 ), m0=100, m1=10) # Change he kwargs at run time.

# array([[[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
#         [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
#         [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]],

#        [[100., 101., 102., 103., 104.],
#         [110., 111., 112., 113., 114.],
#         [120., 121., 122., 123., 124.]],

#        [[200., 201., 202., 203., 204.],
#         [210., 211., 212., 213., 214.],
#         [220., 221., 222., 223., 224.]],

#        [[300., 301., 302., 303., 304.],
#         [310., 311., 312., 313., 314.],
#         [320., 321., 322., 323., 324.]]])
```

Comment: What if I need to pass other arguments into my function, other than x,y?

Comment: @Vranvs.  I've edited the answer to include keyword arguments.